# Laravel Valet not working with Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-valet

I have been trying to use Valet but I found a problem. I created a new Laravel 5.2 project but I can't access the public assets files.

The only information I can tell is this error:

`<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: extension in <b>/Users/tiagocardoso/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/cli/drivers/ValetDriver.php</b> on line <b>121</b><br />`

Chrome Console Information:

`http://ads.dev/css/app.css net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ad Block blocks anything that includes `ads` in the filename.  My thinking is `ads.dev` is causing everything.  Do you have that enabled?

`BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` means your browser is blocking them from loading.

Comment: What the hell, you are right mate. I was not even looking for uBlock. Thanks for solve the problem ^^