# Laravel valet always asks password

Tags: php, laravel, macos-sierra, laravel-valet

After reinstalling macOS, I started setup my dev environment based on Laracasts "Setup a mac dev machine from scratch". At the previous time when I installed php/valet/composer etc, everything was fine, but now the terminal (in every new session) always asks password when I type valet.

I added the composer path to .zshrc

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37489698/laravel-valet-not-working-with-laravel?rq=1)

Comment: This is a weird problem. I have this problem too. Previously I did not have this problem. Just weird.

@Bhavik Shah, your solution is not related to this problem.

Comment: @RuChernChong Yeah, this is a weird problem, but the laravel installer works fine.

Comment: @Arthanis Yeah! Exactly!

Answer (score 3):

In order to get this going you can run the following command:

```
$ valet trust
```

This will let you enter the password once, and remember it.
Using the trust command, you indicate that the current machine can be trusted for development, and Valet will stop asking for the password.

Answer (score 2):

Your macOS native apache might be running, try stopping it

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

Comment: Thanks, worked for me. I think this may be the problem for all Mac users.

Answer (score 0):

running `sudo valet start` fixed it for me.